# App for WP 7.1 with Async CTP dosn't work on WP 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, async-ctp, windows-phone-8

I just finished installing the SDK of WP8 and wanted to try my app now compatible with WP 7.1 and so I opened the project and compiled, but gives me errors only on the parts that use "async" and "await". I used Async CTP, but doesn't like much WP8. How can I fix and, above all, how can I make it so that the app functions both on WP and WP 8 7.1?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot build Windows Phone 7.1 applications on Windows Phone 8 SDK without upgrading your project.

If you want to maintain WP7.1 version of your application with async/await feature, you will have to have Visual Studio Express 2010 for WP7.1 + Async CTP 3 along with VS2012 Express for Windows Phone.

UPDATE: There is a way to compile WP7 applications on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone by using this nifty [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). However, note that it is currently in prerelease version.

Comment: Ok, but on the Store? How it works? Can I upload separatly a version for WP7.1 and a version for WP8?

Comment: Yes you can. You can upload multiple assemblies for same application and then upgrade each of them independently.

Comment: I don't know about Facebook (since I don't have a WP8 device yet :( ), but the functionality is built in into DevCenter itself.

Comment: Facebook has uploaded 4.0 version for WP8 [http://www.windowsphone.com/it-it/store/app/facebook/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e](http://www.windowsphone.com/it-it/store/app/facebook/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e), but anyway it works even WP7.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install this:
https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Blog about the targeting pack:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

> Today, we are proud to announce an update to the Async Targeting Pack
>   we had previously released. The previous targeting pack allowed you to
>   use await when targeting .NET Framework 4.0 and Silverlight 5. Our
>   updated targeting pack allows you to use await in Visual Studio 2012
>   when targeting any of the following platforms (or higher versions):
>
> .NET Framework 4.0 (with KB2468871) Silverlight 4 Windows Phone 7.5
>   and portable class libraries targeting those platforms

Comment: So, if I use this library in the my app, and upload the update in DevCenter, will the my app be compatible with WP8?

Comment: Yes but it would have anyway, the targeting pack lets you dev 7.1 apps in vs2012.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't totally correct, if you're not using the async ctp, you should be able to develop wp7.1 apps in vs2012 without the targeting pack.